# Laravel showing errors when migrating

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

So, I have new fresh laravel installation on my pc. I installed "chatter" which is forum package for laravel and on my project I have laravel's auth system.

I tried migrating, but I got errors:

```
[2019-01-03 09:55:14] local.ERROR: SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'users' already exists (SQL: create table `users` (`id` int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key, `name` varchar(255) not null, `email` varchar(255) not null, `email_verified_at` timestamp null, `password` varchar(255) not null, `remember_token` varchar(100) null, `created_at` timestamp null, `updated_at` timestamp null) default character set utf8mb4 collate 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci') {"exception":"[object] (Illuminate\\Database\\QueryException(code: 42S01): SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'users' already exists (SQL: create table `users` (`id` int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key, `name` varchar(255) not null, `email` varchar(255) not null, `email_verified_at` timestamp null, `password` varchar(255) not null, `remember_token` varchar(100) null, `created_at` timestamp null, `updated_at` timestamp null) default character set utf8mb4 collate 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci') at C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\GrandSchool\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Database\\Connection.php:664, PDOException(code: 42S01): SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'users' already exists at C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\GrandSchool\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Database\\Connection.php:458)
[stacktrace]
#0 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\GrandSchool\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Database\\Connection.php(624): Illuminate\\Database\\Connection->runQueryCallback('create table `u...', Array, Object(Closure))
#1 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\GrandSchool\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Database\\Connection.php(459): Illuminate\\Database\\Connection->run('create table `u...', Array, Object(Closure))
#2 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\GrandSchool\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Database\\Schema\\Blueprint.php(97): Illuminate\\Database\\Connection->statement('create table `u...')
#3 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\GrandSchool\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Database\\Schema\\Builder.php(264): Illuminate\\Database\\Schema\\Blueprint->build(Object(Illuminate\\Database\\MySqlConnection), Object(Illuminate\\Database\\Schema\\Grammars\\MySqlGrammar))
#4 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\GrandSchool\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Database\\Schema\\Builder.php(165): Illuminate\\Database\\Schema\\Builder->build(Object(Illuminate\\Database\\Schema\\Blueprint))
#5 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\GrandSchool\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Support\\Facades\\Facade.php(237): Illuminate\\Database\\Schema\\Builder->create('users', Object(Closure))
#6 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\GrandSchool\\database\\migrations\\2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table.php(24): Illuminate\\Support\\Facades\\Facade::__callStatic('create', Array)
#7 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\GrandSchool\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Database\\Migrations\\Migrator.php(360): CreateUsersTable->up()
#8 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\GrandSchool\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Database\\Migrations\\Migrator.php(367): Illuminate\\Database\\Migrations\\Migrator->Illuminate\\Database\\Migrations\\{closure}()
#9 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\GrandSchool\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Database\\Migrations\\Migrator.php(178): Illuminate\\Database\\Migrations\\Migrator->runMigration(Object(CreateUsersTable), 'up')
#10 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\GrandSchool\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Database\\Migrations\\Migrator.php(147): Illuminate\\Database\\Migrations\\Migrator->runUp('C:\\\\xampp\\\\htdocs...', 1, false)
#11 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\GrandSchool\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Database\\Migrations\\Migrator.php(96): Illuminate\\Database\\Migrations\\Migrator->runPending(Array, Array)
#12 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\GrandSchool\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Database\\Console\\Migrations\\MigrateCommand.php(71): Illuminate\\Database\\Migrations\\Migrator->run(Array, Array)
#13 [internal function]: Illuminate\\Database\\Console\\Migrations\\MigrateCommand->handle()
#14 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\GrandSchool\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod.php(29): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#15 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\GrandSchool\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod.php(87): Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod::Illuminate\\Container\\{closure}()
#16 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\GrandSchool\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod.php(31): Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod::callBoundMethod(Object(Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application), Array, Object(Closure))
#17 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\GrandSchool\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Container\\Container.php(572): Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod::call(Object(Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application), Array, Array, NULL)
#18 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\GrandSchool\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Console\\Command.php(183): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->call(Array)
#19 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\GrandSchool\\vendor\\symfony\\console\\Command\\Command.php(255): Illuminate\\Console\\Command->execute(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Illuminate\\Console\\OutputStyle))
#20 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\GrandSchool\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Console\\Command.php(170): Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Command\\Command->run(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Illuminate\\Console\\OutputStyle))
#21 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\GrandSchool\\vendor\\symfony\\console\\Application.php(901): Illuminate\\Console\\Command->run(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\ConsoleOutput))
#22 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\GrandSchool\\vendor\\symfony\\console\\Application.php(262): Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Application->doRunCommand(Object(Illuminate\\Database\\Console\\Migrations\\MigrateCommand), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\ConsoleOutput))
#23 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\GrandSchool\\vendor\\symfony\\console\\Application.php(145): Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Application->doRun(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\ConsoleOutput))
#24 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\GrandSchool\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Console\\Application.php(89): Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Application->run(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\ConsoleOutput))
#25 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\GrandSchool\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Console\\Kernel.php(122): Illuminate\\Console\\Application->run(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\ConsoleOutput))
#26 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\GrandSchool\\artisan(37): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Console\\Kernel->handle(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\ConsoleOutput))
#27 {main}
"}
```

Comment: How do you start the migration?

Comment: Chatter package doesn't use `users` table in their migrations, you must have an other package or problem

Comment: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/code-review/sqlstate42s01-base-table-or-view-already-exists-1050-table-users-already-exists it might works to you

Comment: please check your database the error shows that your table already exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to delete **users table** table from the database also delete users entries from **migrations** table.

After, To run all of your outstanding migrations, execute the migrate Artisan command: `php artisan migrate`

---

Another Solution is: The `migrate:refresh` command will roll back all of your migrations and then execute the  `migrate` command. This command effectively re-creates your entire database:

```
php artisan migrate:refresh

// Refresh the database and run all database seeds...
php artisan migrate:refresh --seed
```

Comment: Yup, that's it! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try remove all the tables first before migrate:

```
php artisan migrate:fresh --seed
```

or

```
php artisan migrate:fresh
```

Answer (score 0):

try it once

```
php artisan migrate:fresh
```

or truncate migrations table before run migratte